# Compiling container operations to efficient incremental code

Tags: algorithm, optimization, collections, compiler-optimization

Most programming languages nowadays provide containers like list, set, multiset, map. Operations on all elements of a container e.g. `copy_if` or `transform` normally take O(n) time. Lazy evaluation can make this sublinear if you only need the first few elements of the result, but it's back to linear if you need the full result.

Consider for example the following implementation of the DPLL algorithm for propositional satisfiability. It's essentially a translation of the pseudocode to C++, thus optimized for readability. But each step takes time linear in the number of variables, so even if it could guess all the assignments correctly the first time, total time and memory consumption would be quadratic in the number of variables, making the implementation too slow to use in practice. This is true even if we apply well-known optimizations like passing containers by constant reference and using lazy evaluation anywhere it might avoid unnecessary work.

Efficient implementations of DPLL use incremental techniques, where instead of scanning and copying entire containers, only the consequences of making a small change like assigning a single variable are computed, using O(1) time and memory per step.

A human can translate pseudocode or unoptimized reference implementation to an efficient incremental implementation; this is what we do when we write practical SAT solvers, theorem provers etc. The price we pay is to thenceforth work with a large, complex body of optimized code, which is much more difficult than working with a concise description of the mathematical logic.

What we ideally want is a higher-level compiler, that can compile the unoptimized reference implementation into efficient incremental code.

My question is: has any work yet been done on such a thing? Are there any existing implementations, partial implementations or discussions to look at?  Higher-level optimization of container operations is not entirely unknown in principle, e.g. SQL query optimizers, Haskell loop fusion, but I'm not aware of anything that tries to go as far as I'm looking for here.

Unoptimized reference implementation (simple translation of pseudocode) of DPLL:

```
bool dpll(map<Var, bool> m, set<set<Literal>> clauses) {
  clauses = eval(m, clauses);

  // Solved
  if (isFalse(clauses))
    return false;
  if (isTrue(clauses))
    return true;

  // Unit clause
  auto unitClauses =
      copy_if(clauses, [](set<Literal> clause) { return clause.size() == 1; });
  if (unitClauses.size()) {
    auto x = front(front(unitClauses));
    return dpll(m + makeMap(x.var, x.pol), clauses);
  }

  // Pure literal
  auto pureVars =
      copy_if(vars(clauses), [=](Var x) { return pure(x, clauses); });
  if (pureVars.size()) {
    auto x = front(pureVars);
    return dpll(m + makeMap(x, pol(x, clauses)), clauses);
  }

  // Choice
  auto x = choose(vars(clauses));
  return dpll(m + makeMap(x, false), clauses) ||
         dpll(m + makeMap(x, true), clauses);
}
```

Similar reference implementation of helper functions: https://github.com/russellw/ayane/blob/master/logic/dpll.cpp

Comment: Sounds strongly related to a lot of work done in the 90's on making pure functional operations efficient for aggregate data types (e.g set A[i] without copying A). Abstract interpretation was a favored approach as I recall. See for example http://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~gopi/docs/sem2c.pdf . In many cases pure functional optimizations can be adapted to other settings by adopting continuation representations.

Comment: @Gene Thanks! Checking out the reference, and yes, the point about pure functional operations is a good one - in this scenario, it's reasonable to stipulate that code be either pure functional or easily convertible to such.